# Set field via URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to have a field in the current item be changed by clicking a URL? The field would be a choice field with predefined choices.

Such as if the item field is currently:
Status: 2
If a user clicks the link, the field would now be:
Status: 3

If not, is there any other way for a user to easily change a field in the current item without actually haveing to visit the item?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any problem with this method?http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/05/13/bulk-editing-of-sharepoint-list-items/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not Out Of The Box (OOTB) - but you've a few options.

- Write an ASPX page to do what you want
- Use something like [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) and javascript to update the list item via the web services.
- Use the [Client Object Model](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=client%20object%20model) (2010 only)

*By the way - changing stuff on a 'get' can be dangerous as you can do malicious things - for example imagine you have a page that deletes the users account without any prompting (exact example doesn't matter) - what if someone clicks on that link by mistake or even worse what about an email sent with an image with that page as source URL - simply viewing the email could delete the users account.*

Comment: Or, even simpler - imagine the SharePoint search crawler open the GET link. No user interaction, but the link has been accessed!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by using a GET request, but SharePoint 2010 is offering a RESTful API to manage ListItems from any client

The REST API is located within the virtual WebServices folgder under each SharePoint Site.
http://YourSharePointSite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc.

To perform an update on SharePoint ListItems you have to create a PUT Request. For more information on SharePoints REST API you should have a look at [this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587.aspx), there are also a lot of samples linked from this article.

Thorsten